# How to package Quicklook plugins for AppStore

Tags: mac-appstore, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

I developed a bunch of specialized Quicklook plugins and would like to share them through the App store. Is there a way of packaging them and distributing them through the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

Put them inside `MyApp.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/`

More info on [Apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH4-SW4).

> When Quick Look searches for a generator to use, it first looks for it in the bundle of the associated application and then in the standard file-system locations (...)

If You do not have any app and only the plugins, I think you can make a single view application describing the plugins or something like this. However I can't find the reference for this.

Comment: That's exactly what I have. It's only the plugins I would like to distribute and I cant find anything about best practices what so ever for that problem.